# In Python, how to know whether objects can be compared?

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison-operators, abstract-base-class

With [abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html), Python provides a way to know the behavior of objects without actually trying it out. In the standard library, we have some ABCs defined for containers in [collections.abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc). For example, one can test that an argument is iterable:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
def function(argument):
    if not isinstance(argument, Iterable):
        raise TypeError('argument must be iterable.')
    # do stuff with the argument
```

I was hoping that there would be one such ABC for deciding whether instances of a class can be compared but couldn't find one. Testing for the existence of `__lt__` methods is not sufficient. For example, dictionaries cannot be compared but `__lt__` is still defined (same with `object` actually).

```
>>> d1, d2 = {}, {}
>>> d1 < d2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()
>>> hasattr(d1, '__lt__')
True
```

So my question is: is there a simple way to do it without doing the comparisons themselves and catching the `TypeError`?

My use case is similar to a sorted container: I'd like to raise an exception when I insert the first element and not to wait for a second element. I thought about comparing the element with itself, but is there a better approach:

```
def insert(self, element):
    try:
        element < element
    except TypeError as e:
        raise TypeError('element must be comparable.')
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such ABC, because an ABC *only dictates what attributes are there*. ABCs cannot test for the nature of the implementation (or even if those attributes are actually methods).

The presence of comparison methods (`__lt__`, `__gt__`, `__le__`, `__ge__` and `__eq__`) does *not* dictate that the class is going to be comparable with everything else. *Usually* you can only compare objects of the same type or class of types; numbers with numbers for example.

As such, *most* types<sup>*</sup> implement the comparison methods but return the `NotImplemented` sentinel object when comparing with other incompatible types. Returning `NotImplemented` signals to Python to give the right-hand value a say in the matter too. If `a.__lt__(b)` returns `NotImplemented` then `b.__gt__(a)` is tested too.

The base `object` provides default implementations for the methods, returning `NotImplemented`:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> Foo() < Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: Foo() < Foo()
>>> Foo().__lt__
<method-wrapper '__lt__' of Foo object at 0x10f1cf860>
>>> Foo().__lt__(Foo())
NotImplemented
```

which is exactly what `dict.__lt__` does:

```
>>> {}.__lt__({})
NotImplemented
```

Numbers, however, only return `NotImplemented` when the other type is not comparable:

```
>>> (1).__lt__(2)
True
>>> (1).__lt__('2')
NotImplemented
>>> 1 < 2
True
>>> 1 < '2'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
```

As such, your *best* choice is to simply catch the `TypeError` thrown when values are not comparable.

---

<sup>*</sup> I am not aware of any types in the Python 3 standard library that do not implement the comparison methods at this time.

Comment: ABCs do not only state what attributes are there. That's all they can *enforce*, but since they are opt-in (need to inherit from it or explicitly register with it), most ABCs can and do define a contract. It is more than reasonable to assume, when `isinstance(x, abc.Sized)`, that `x.__len__` is a method returning a non-negative integer. It isn't checked programmatically, of course, but with Python being as dynamic as it is, nothing can really be checked.

Comment: @delnan: sure, that is the intention of ABCs. But since the contract for the comparison methods is to return `NotImplemented` when passed an object type that is incompatible, you cannot test for implementation of that contract to that extent using ABCs.

Comment: True, the double dispatch makes it more complicated. I'm mostly objecting to the general statements "only dictates what attributes are there" and "(or even if those attributes are actually methods)".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Do you know if there are many cases of objects that can be compared with other types, besides numbers?

Comment: @Fracis: in Python 2 almost all types are comparable to other types; this is a frequent source of bugs (especially when numbers and strings are involved); this was done to support sorting heterogenous sequences. In Python 3 I can't currently think of any examples outside of numbers (where floats and integers have clearly defined ordering).

Comment: Something interesting with respect to the implicit contract of ABCs is the example of `Hashable`: a list is not hashable, a tuple is (even if its content is not); both have the `__hash__` attribute but it's not callable (`None`) for the list and for the tuple you get a `TypeError` if some of the content is not hashable. That is, indeed, another example of an ABC not being able to tell the full story.

Comment: Contrary to user395760's assertion, only some ABCs are opt-in. ABCs like `collections.abc.Sized` (there is no `abc.Sized`) automatically detect objects with the corresponding method and return `True` for `isinstance`, without any explicit inheritance or registration.

Comment: @user2357112 that’s not what Delnan was talking about. Yes, many collection.abc ABCs (all the non-datatype classes, basically) define a [`__subclasshook__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__), so `isonstance()` and `issubclass()` tests succeed when the methods are present. He was arguing about what will happen when you call the methods, as ABCs can’t enforce implementation or argument or return types.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The comment doesn't make it explicit, but the "need to inherit from it or explicitly register with it" part suggests a belief that `isinstance` won't return `True` unless you explicitly inherit or register. I don't know what else delnan might have been thinking `register` opts into, besides `True` results for `isinstance` tests.